# How to avoid re-downloading of Maven artifacts when deactivating a mirror in settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I successfully use a `settings.mirrors.mirror` directive in my `settings.xml` with a `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` setting. Occasionally I need to deactivate it if the mirror is unavailable so that downloads are made from the repositories specified in POM of the default one.

Then, all artifacts which are available locally and have been downloaded through the mirror are downloaded again which isn't necessary and costs data volume and time. If I reactivate the mirror the same happens for all locally available artifacts. How to avoid this?

I'm using Maven 3.5.2. The mirror is an Artifactory 5.x instance running in my LAN.

I know that I could work around this by using an `iptables` rule or `squid` URL rewriting (for non-SSL connections), but that's no the answer I'm seeking.